# Grouping Algorithm

Tags: javascript, python, algorithm, grouping

```
Fruits = [
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:good,  price:medium},
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:bad,   price:medium},
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:good,  price:low},
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:bad,   price:medium},
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:good,  price:medium},
 {name:apple, color:green, taste:bad,   price:medium},
 {name:apple, color:green, taste:bad,   price:medium}
];
```

Here I want to count apples of one kind, i.e apples which are red, taste good & price medium, for this type the count is 2 so one object'll be removed and a new property count'll be added to the first one.

Similarly I want to count apples which are red, taste bad & price medium,
apples which are red, taste good & price low.

I want to group these fruits with every possible combination of their properties, find similar ones, count and remove the duplicates.

**Expected Result**

```
Fruits = [
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:good,  price:medium, count:2},
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:bad,   price:medium, count:2},
 {name:apple, color:red,   taste:good,  price:low, count:1},
 {name:apple, color:green, taste:badd,  price:medium, count:2},
];
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Just sort them.  That puts all duplicates together in a single block, so you can count them easily in a second pass.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because this isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes i know, i don't ask every problem i counter, only the ones i can't solve

Comment: @NestedWeb so where is your attempted solution, and what precisely is the problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two approaches to solve this problem:

1. `O(nlogn)` time worst case, very little space: **sort the elements,
   and then iterate** and count, identical elements are adjacent to each
   other, so the counting is fairly easy.
2. `O(n)` time (average case) and space: **build a hash-map** where its key is the description of the apple, and the value is its number of occurances, iterate the list and for each element update the hash map.

Note that it cannot be done better i.e. `O(n)` time and sublinear space, since this is a special case of [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem), which cannot be solved in linear time and sublinear space.

Answer (score 0):

In Python, this can be done like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
keys = ["name", "color", "taste", "price"]
d, get_keys = defaultdict(int), itemgetter(*keys)

# Group the items based on their name, color, taste and price and count them
for item in Fruits:
    d[get_keys(item)] += 1

# Unwrap the groups along with their count    
result = []
for key in d:
    temp = dict(zip(keys, key))
    temp["count"] = d[key]
    result.append(temp)

print result
```

**Output**

```
[{'color': 'green',
  'count': 1,
  'name': 'apple',
  'price': 'medium',
  'taste': 'good'},
 {'color': 'red',
  'count': 2,
  'name': 'apple',
  'price': 'medium',
  'taste': 'good'},
 {'color': 'red',
  'count': 1,
  'name': 'apple',
  'price': 'low',
  'taste': 'good'},
 {'color': 'green',
  'count': 2,
  'name': 'apple',
  'price': 'medium',
  'taste': 'bad'},
 {'color': 'red',
  'count': 2,
  'name': 'apple',
  'price': 'medium',
  'taste': 'bad'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, if you are going to count something then try the collections.Counter class; and looking at your data, you can use a collections.namedtuple to track the field names.

Here is my code:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, namedtuple
>>> from pprint import pprint as pp
>>> 
>>> Fr = namedtuple('Fr', 'name, colour, taste, price')
>>> Fruits = [Fr(*datum) for datum in [('apple', 'red', 'good', 'medium'),
                  ('apple', 'red', 'bad', 'medium'),
                  ('apple', 'red', 'good', 'low'),
                  ('apple', 'red', 'bad', 'medium'),
                  ('apple', 'red', 'good', 'medium'),
                  ('apple', 'green', 'bad', 'medium'),
                  ('apple', 'green', 'bad', 'medium')]]
>>> pp(Fruits)
[Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='good', price='medium'),
 Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='bad', price='medium'),
 Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='good', price='low'),
 Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='bad', price='medium'),
 Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='good', price='medium'),
 Fr(name='apple', colour='green', taste='bad', price='medium'),
 Fr(name='apple', colour='green', taste='bad', price='medium')]
>>> counted = Counter(Fruits)
>>> pp(dict(counted))
{Fr(name='apple', colour='green', taste='bad', price='medium'): 2,
 Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='bad', price='medium'): 2,
 Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='good', price='low'): 1,
 Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='good', price='medium'): 2}
>>> pp(counted.most_common())
[(Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='good', price='medium'), 2),
 (Fr(name='apple', colour='green', taste='bad', price='medium'), 2),
 (Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='bad', price='medium'), 2),
 (Fr(name='apple', colour='red', taste='good', price='low'), 1)]
>>>
```